# How to unlock the last level?

Tags: face-raiders

In Face Raiders, the level after the Bonus Level has a Keyhole on it, signifying that it is locked. When I press it, It says:

```
                                   ???
                            Try merging faces in
                            Nintendo 3DS camera!
                              Keep Collecting!
```

Does this mean that I have to go to the camera and *actually* merge faces? Or do I continue collecting faces like the game asks me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you need to go to the 3DS camera and merge the faces. That's the requirement for unlocking the Bonus Level.

The steps for doing so are as follows:

1. Go to the 3DS Camera.
2. Flip the switch on the bottom right corner of the screen.
3. On the menu that appears, tap the camera icon (located on the rightmost side).
4. On the next menu, select the head with a question mark icon.
5. Find someone (or something) and take a picture of it.

Do it a few times and it should unlock the bonus stage.

If it doesn't, try the following: Look to see if the UFO brings some merged faces over to the main stages. If so, play that stage, and locate and destroy the UFO with the merged face. This will "rescue" that face. After successfully completing the stage with the rescuing, you should unlock the Bonus Level (provided you completed all previous stages).

Hope this answer helps!